# Installing Oracle JDeveloper Studio Edition 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: software-installation, oracle

Please someone help me with the installation of oracle jdev.
The instructions in the internet only support the old versions.
The new version has a .bin file and a folder which contains some other installation data and I don't know what to do with that folder!
I tried this commands which caused error..

```
chmod 777 jdev_suite_122130_linux64.bin
sudo ./jdev_suite_122130_linux64.bin
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR: Installer execution failed (1).
```

Comment: run it like this `./jdev_suite_122130_linux64.bin` remove the sudo

Comment: @George I tried this one but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Is this the entire output of `sudo ./jdev_suite_122130_linux64.bin`?

Answer (score 2):

To set up the installer if required the right command should have been: `chmod +x jdev_suite_122130_linux64.bin`. But nonetheless, run it without `sudo`:

```
./jdev_suite_122130_linux64.bin
```

Next time check whether it's executable with:

```
ls -l jdev_suite_122130_linux64.bin
```

Excerpts from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/ASINS/preparing.htm#ASINS350)

Below are some additional considerations to make prior to running the installer:

- On UNIX operating systems, Oracle recommends that you set the umask to 027 on your system prior to installation. This ensures that file permissions will be set properly during installation. Use the following command:

  ```
  umask 027
  ```

  - You must enter this command in the same terminal window from which you plan to run the product installer.
- On UNIX operating systems, do not run the installation program as the root user. The installer startup validation will fail and you will not be able to continue.
- When managing a product installation (for example, applying patches, or starting Managed Servers), you must use the same user ID as was used to perform the initial product installation.

From the above the new permissions you set `777` will not let the installer go forward. Hence you need to take it back to the default then follow the instructions above in the **excerpt**. The was  o requirement to change the permissions in the first place. If you downloaded the `zip` file then `unzip` again and check the permissions with `ls -l <file_name>`. Armed with this information you can now follow the recommended way to run the installer.

See page 15 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/jdev/install/OJDIG.pdf)

Comment: I tried it and this error appears again : Launcher log file is /tmp/OraInstall2017-11-20_12-22-40PM/launcher2017-11-20_12-22-40PM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . Done
Self extraction to /tmp/sfx_KsxhGM failed.
The log is located here: /tmp/OraInstall2017-11-20_12-22-40PM/launcher2017-11-20_12-22-40PM.log.
ERROR: Installer execution failed (1).

Comment: Please reextract that file and check the default permission on that installer then make executable if not already then try again

Comment: Or let me see the default permission o. It.

Comment: How should I see the default permission?

Comment: was it the zip version you downloaded

Comment: It's a 2Gig .bin file and a 450Mg zip file

Comment: Thanks for the information. I used umask 027 and I checked the permission. It was rwxrwxrwx. I tried to install oracle again but the same error still apears... :(

Comment: I think the problem is because jdev has 2 files for installation.. that zip which is 450Mb is called disk 2 and the oracle webpage says both files (.bin file and .zip file) is required for installing. But when I try to run the files only .bin file is shown in terminal.